# Find text nodes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, nodes

I found [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) but my problem is that although I can go like

```
$(elem)
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).each(function() {
     this.nodeValue = //stuff
  });
```

I am trying to figure out how I can combine `this.nodeType` with the `before` and `after` nodes because some of the stuff I need can appear as a combination of the `this.nodeValue + before`, `this.nodeValue` or `this.nodeValue + after` if that makes sense and I need to test EACH node value as well as it in combination with the previous and next ?

Comment: Post a sample markup code on how you have it and desired result explaining what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you wanted to get the `prev` and next `node` when you hit the text node. See below,

```
var elContents = $('#test').contents();
elContents.each(function(idx, el) {
    if (el.nodeType == 3) {
        if (idx == 0) {
           prev = null;
           next = elContents.get(idx + 1);
        } else if (idx == elContents.length - 1) {
           prev = elContents.get(idx - 1);
           next = null;
        } else {
           next = elContents.get(idx + 1);
           prev = elContents.get(idx - 1);
        }

        //below is demo code
        $('#result').append ("<b>Prev: </b>" + $(prev).text() + " <b>Cur: </b>" + $(el).text() + "<b> Next: </b>" + $(next).text() + '<br />');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SFmRR/

**Note:** In the demo, the elements inside div doesn't have any additional space/line breaks because when you iterate over `contents()` It includes line breaks and space as textNode.

Comment: @Andy It is the same.. except that you get `index` and `element` passed to you by jQuery instead of manual iterator.